# Sum all columns in a row

Tags: oracle, rdbms

How can I get a total results of all my rows? (for **ORACLE**)

```
SELECT
 NAME,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_1 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_2 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_3 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK3,
FROM TABLE_NAME
 WHERE GROUP BY NAME;
```

I have this results:
Name week1 week2 week3

```
Anne    1 2 3
Bob     3 1 0
Charlie 4 5 1
```

I want this result:

```
Anne    1 2 3
Bob     3 1 0
Charlie 4 5 1
Total   8 8 4
```

Comment: Just a hint: instead of filling the fields `ASSIST_1`, `ASSIST_2`... with `YES` or `NO` and translate it then to `1` or `0`, you can easily use `1` and `0` for those fields and thus get rid of `CASE WHEN`

Comment: @B001 it isn't real data of course, just an example. There is more than a binary result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on @Nicholas answer:

```
SELECT
   CASE GROUPING(NAME) WHEN 0 THEN NAME ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS NAME,
   SUM (WEEK1) AS WEEK1,
   SUM (WEEK2) AS WEEK2,
   SUM (WEEK3) AS WEEK3
      FROM (
         SELECT
            NAME,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_1 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK1,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_2 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ASSIST_3 = 'YES' THEN 1 END) WEEK3,
               FROM TABLE_NAME
               WHERE GROUP BY (NAME)
          GROUP BY ROLLUP(NAME)
          ORDER BY GROUPING(NAME);
```

Give this result:

```
Anne    1 2 3
Bob     3 1 0
Charlie 4 5 1
Total   8 8 4
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get a total results of all my rows?

By using `rollup()` extension of the `group by` clause. Something like this(just an example):

```
-- sample of date from your question
 with t1(uname, c1, c2, c3) as(
     select 'Anne'   , 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
     select 'Bob'    , 3, 1, 0 from dual union all
     select 'Charlie', 4, 5, 1 from dual
  )
  -- actual query
  select case grouping(uname) 
           when 0 then uname 
           else 'Total' end 
         as uname1
       , sum(c1) as c1
       , sum(c2) as c2
       , sum(c3) as c3  
    from t1
   group by rollup(uname) 
   order by grouping(uname)
```

Result:

```
UNAME1          C1         C2         C3
------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Anne             1          2          3
Bob              3          1          0
Charlie          4          5          1
Total            8          8          4


4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Use the full power of group by rollup: Instead of NVL, it is better (cleaner) to use something like `case grouping(name) when 0 name else 'Total' end`. And to get proper ordering, add `order by grouping(name)` at the end.

Comment: @mathguy Valid points. Thank you. Of course,  it's better to use `case` expression combined with `grouping()` over simple `NVL` not only because it's a bit cleaner but also to avoid erroneously assigning(in this case) `Total` to a NULL username.

Comment: :-) actually that's what I meant by "cleaner". Then, in more complicated aggregates with rollup, you can give different "total" descriptions to the totals by different criteria.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov with `t1` you are assuming that I know the values in the table and I will type one by one

Comment: @xedo No, it's a sample of the data from your question. Nothing more. I used `with` clause so I wouldn't create and populate a table. Do not look at the `with` clause look at, and use the actual query, and change `t1` to your table name

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` with `SUM` values

```
WITH t1(name, week1, week2, week3) AS
  ( SELECT 'Anne', 1, 2, 3 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 3, 1, 0 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Charlie', 4, 5, 1 FROM dual
  ),
  s AS
  (SELECT 'Total' name,
    SUM(week1) week1,
    SUM(week2) week2,
    SUM(week2) week3
  FROM t1
  )
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM s;
```

**Result:**

```
NAME    WEEK1   WEEK2   WEEK3
Anne    1        2       3
Bob     3        1       0
Charlie 4        5       1
Total   8        8       8
```